# How to measure mA level DC current at double MCU VCC

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

I want to measure a small 1-20mA current with my MCU. It has a transimpedance amplifier I thought would be useful for the task. I'd like to to just measure the voltage difference across a resistor. The only problem is the voltage for the current is around 6V and the MCU VCC is 3V. How can I safely measure the current here without blowing up my MCU. If I can I'd like to do it cheaply and as small as possible. One last thing if it makes a difference, the current can be changed but once it's set it'll be pretty steady state. So I don't need to measure a waveform or anything, I just want to take a sample or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing the measurement just as a lab experiment or calibration step where the readings only need to be taken once or twice then the appropriate way to do this is with a battery operated MultiMeter to measure the voltage across your current sensing resistor.

If on the other hand you need to be able to take readings using your MCU in a live product environment, even though that may be just a couple of readings per session, then you want to look for a specialty chip called a high side current monitor chip. These have a pair of inputs that detect the voltage drop across a high side current sense resistor and translate that voltage down to a low side output that can be scaled to your MCU input.

There are quite a range of these devices available that have performance ratings over a wide scope with pricing proportional to the performance and features. One part that you may want to consider is the [ST TSC101 part](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/tsc101-957388.pdf) that is easy to use with few added parts.

[image]

*(picture from above linked data sheet)*

Comment: That's a cool part I didn't even know those existed.  Thanks!

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy, there are many more parts of this kind, TI INA199 family, INA219 with digital I2C interface, Zetex ZXCT11xx family, etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

The current you want to measure comes from a current source.  That means the voltage can rise as high as 6 V in order to get the specified current to flow, but it won't do that unless the resistance is too high. In your case, you choose a resistor that gives you 3V at 20mA, and you're good to go.  Ohm's law will give you that resistance value.  Of course, you may want to leave a little extra room, as usual.

Comment: This answer may be counter productive. Normally the current sense resistor wants to be as small of ohms value as possible so that it is as transparent as possible to the power delivery system. The trade off comes in how small can it get before it is too difficult to measure the voltage drop across it. In a typical load situation one tries to match the power supply that drives the load as close to the load voltage requirements as possible. On top if that most devices that are a load want a pretty constant voltage. For a 6V load type situation to follow your idea would require (continued)

Comment: (continued from above)  a 9V supply with full load current passing through the sense resistor. This would be an unconscionable waste of power. And as the load current changed the net voltage delivered to the load would vary a lot and may very well violate the working voltage range of the load. There may be some current measurement applications where your idea could work but in some 45 years in this electronics business I have seen very few such applications.

Comment: True, but I interpreted the question as if the current was an instrumentation signal. I guess he didn't say "4-20 ma" so maybe you're right.